# Android app to keep track of what food each of my friends likes/dislikes

Tags: android, project-management, productivity, accessibility, cooking

It should store, along with what you cooked, for each person, what you gave that person to eat, and, whether they liked it, or they didn't like it.

You may even be able to give a rating, and store notes.

If a response was not available you may be able to store a rating based on what impression.

Then, in the app, you can click on a person, and view what they liked the most and the least.

Based on this, you can make decisions such as what to cook and what to shop for.

It could be a useful app.

---

Most people I would have a chance to cook something for would be on Facebook/Messenger WhatsApp or my Android Contacts(/Phone) stock-built-in application.

It would be nice if I had an application, that could connect to these apps, make me search for a contact (perhaps, though a service provided by the application), provide result lists, and allow me to select, contacts, to import.

This way the contact, an identity, in computer science space, would be somehow inseparable (later, third party apps built for even greater purposes, could connect to various apps to retrieve, and form a basis for providing the service they provide, the contacts, and, recognize, when these are the same.

---

This is the contacts side of the app I wanted to describe at first.

But the app must be able to connect to apps such as cooking apps and notes apps, and do the following.

It imports meal or meal note Information from these apps (including, for example, when a meal was cooked).